# How to get ob_start() working correctly

Tags: php, html, buffer

Im getting an error that states:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/21/10941021/html/index.php:4) in /home/content/21/10941021/html/register.php on line 66

Im thinking I need to put an ob_start() to get the buffering working correctly but I can't get it down. My codes where the problems are include:

```
<div class="lower-body">
<div class="left-lower">Create an account</div>
<div id="account-first">
<?php ob_start();
if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])){
    echo 'You\'ve been registered successfully!';
    echo 'Please check email and activate account!'; 
}else {

if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
    $register_data = array(
        'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
        'lastname'  => $_POST['lastname'],
        'username'  => $_POST['username'],
        'password'  => $_POST['password'],
        'email'     => $_POST['email'],
        'zipcode'   => $_POST['zipcode']
        );

    register_user($register_data);
    header('Location: register.php?sucess');
    exit();
} else if(empty($errors) === false){
    echo output_errors($errors);
    }
}
ob_end_flush();?>
```

and then line 4 is this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'includes/overall/head.php';
?>
```

any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure `ob_start` is called before any output.

Comment: @musa: not true. you can ob_start() anytime you want, including AFTER other output has been performed. it's the header() calls that cause the error, and THAT has to be done before any output.

Comment: @MarcB How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @MarcB if you call `ob_start` before any output then `header` will not cause those errors.

Comment: @user2127663: you can only call `header()` if **NO** output whatsoever has been sent to the client. that means your 3 `<div>` lines are causing the error, because those are output.

Comment: So are you saying somehow remove the divs?

Answer (score 0):

`header('Location: register.php?sucess');` should be before any output like `echo`

EDIT 1:
use `ob_start();` at the start of php code and `ob_end_flush();` at the end, should solve the problem.

EDIT 2: use this

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div class="lower-body">
<div class="left-lower">Create an account</div>
<div id="account-first">
<?php
...
...
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Such as echo 'You\'ve been registered successfully!';?

Comment: What do you mean by blank lines?

Comment: `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP` refer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: So do you see a way in which I could move the header but get it to work correctly with my code? or do i just need to take out both the echoes?

Comment: Oh interesting. So do that in the top code I have? Ill edit to show

Comment: try `ob_start();header('Location: register.php?sucess');ob_end_flush();exit;`